# TypeError: The view function did not return a valid response. The function either returned None or ended without a return statement

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, chatbot

Kindly let me know where I am not including the return statements. Or is the problem somewhere else. I am using Python 3.6, and Flask. I am trying to make a bot. The bot works fine on the terminal.Now I am trying to give it a UI and using Flask.

```
def chat(user_input):
    print("Start talking with the bot !! Press q to quit ")
    print("You :"+user_input)
    while True:
        #inp=input("You: ")
        if user_input.lower() == "q":
            break

        results = model.predict([bag_of_words(user_input, words)])
        arr_result = results[0]
        print(arr_result)

        # gives index of the greatest number
        results_index = np.argmax(results)
        print('The result_index is '+str(results_index))

        # gives the relevant tag
        tag = labels[results_index]
        print('The tag is ' + tag)
        print('labels are'+str(labels))

        if arr_result[results_index] > 0.6:
            print('arr_result[results_index]>0.6 ' +
                  str(arr_result[results_index]))
            # get a random response from the json file
            for tg in data["intents"]:
                print(tg)
                if tg['tag'] == tag:
                    response = tg['responses']
                    print('the array of response is' + str(response))
                    rand_response = random.choice(response)

                    bot_response = str(rand_response)
                    print("Bot: "+bot_response)
                    return render_template('index.html', user_input=user_input, bot_response=bot_response)
                else:
                    print("Tag not found "+bot_response)
                    return render_template('index.html', user_input=user_input, bot_response="Sorry, I do not understand")

        else:
            bot_response = "Sorry, I do not understand"
            print("Bot: "+bot_response)
            return render_template('index.html', user_input=user_input, bot_response=bot_response)
```

I keep getting following error--

```
127.0.0.1 - - [08/Mar/2020 02:40:27] "[35m[1mPOST /process HTTP/1.1[0m" 500 -
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Kuldeep\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2463, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "C:\Users\Kuldeep\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2449, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "C:\Users\Kuldeep\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1866, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "C:\Users\Kuldeep\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\Users\Kuldeep\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2446, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\Kuldeep\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1952, in full_dispatch_request
    return self.finalize_request(rv)
  File "C:\Users\Kuldeep\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1967, in finalize_request
    response = self.make_response(rv)
  File "C:\Users\Kuldeep\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2097, in make_response
    "The view function did not return a valid response. The"
TypeError: The view function did not return a valid response. The function either returned None or ended without a return statement.
127.0.0.1 - - [08/Mar/2020 02:40:27] "[37mGET /process?__debugger__=yes&cmd=resource&f=style.css HTTP/1.1[0m" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [08/Mar/2020 02:40:27] "[37mGET /process?__debugger__=yes&cmd=resource&f=jquery.js HTTP/1.1[0m" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [08/Mar/2020 02:40:27] "[37mGET /process?__debugger__=yes&cmd=resource&f=debugger.js HTTP/1.1[0m" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [08/Mar/2020 02:40:27] "[37mGET /process?__debugger__=yes&cmd=resource&f=console.png HTTP/1.1[0m" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [08/Mar/2020 02:40:27] "[37mGET /process?__debugger__=yes&cmd=resource&f=ubuntu.ttf HTTP/1.1[0m" 200 -
```

Answer (score 2):

There's an implicit `return None` at the end of the `while` loop.

For a Flask request handler, you probably don't want a loop in that function anyway.

You can simplify things by having only one `return` statement - after all the only thing changing in the various returns is `bot_response`:

```py
def chat(user_input):
    results = model.predict([bag_of_words(user_input, words)])
    arr_result = results[0]
    print(arr_result)
    results_index = np.argmax(results)
    print("The result_index is " + str(results_index))
    tag = labels[results_index]
    print("The tag is " + tag)
    print("labels are " + str(labels))
    bot_response = "Sorry, I do not understand"
    if arr_result[results_index] > 0.6:
        print("arr_result[results_index]>0.6 " + str(arr_result[results_index]))
        # get a random response from the json file
        for tg in data["intents"]:
            print(tg)
            if tg["tag"] == tag:
                response = tg["responses"]
                print("the array of response is" + str(response))
                rand_response = random.choice(response)
                bot_response = str(rand_response)
                print("Bot: " + bot_response)
            else:
                print("Tag not found " + bot_response)
    return render_template("index.html", user_input=user_input, bot_response=bot_response)
```

Comment: Yes. You are absolutely correct. Thank u. Let me correct it real quick.

Answer (score 0):

One issue is that when the user hits 'q' to break from the loop, there is no return made.

Comment: Hey, I made a return under 'q' break. I still get the same error.

Comment: @KDV a closer look at the error shows that the cause for exit is an exception. I could not finds the reason for it at first glance but using a try/except to catch the exception and display it should tell you what is going wrong.

Comment: I used try/except, it simply gives me `TypeError: The view function did not return a valid response. The function either returned None or ended without a return statement.`

Comment: Weird... Did you put the try/except inside of that chat function? If yes, this points to one of your render_template misbehaving. Can you confirm index.html exists and is normally working?
If yes, then it might be some empty value passed to it.

Comment: Yes I placed it inside chat(). index.html is working as it from where I am gettin g user_input

Comment: So... if tg['tag'] == tag is False, you are not setting a bot_response which might be the issue. Also, the 500 happens when visiting /process. Are you 100% sure the issue is with that specific function?

Comment: I am a beginner in Python, so I could be wrong. https://github.com/kumkum22/desktop-tutorial/blob/master/main.py is my code.

Comment: Getting a 404 but just put a bot_response = "" at the beginning of your function to get this possible cause out of the way.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209264/discussion-between-kdv-and-sam).